# Cant import mysql.connector in python

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector

I've installed several types of this mysql-connector such as mysql-connector and mysql-connector-python and mysql-connector-rf.

But it keeps saying its not imported. And when im trying to install the mysql-connector-rf it comes with a big red error message.

This is the error code when im trying to run my test.py:

```
PS C:\Users\Oscar GP\OneDrive - Aalborg Universitet\GPRO\aau\gpro\mysql\opgaveark1> & "C:/Users/Oscar GP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/Oscar GP/OneDrive - 
Aalborg Universitet/GPRO/aau/gpro/mysql/opgaveark1/opgave1/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Oscar GP/OneDrive - Aalborg Universitet/GPRO/aau/gpro/mysql/opgaveark1/opgave1/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
PS C:\Users\Oscar GP\OneDrive - Aalborg Universitet\GPRO\aau\gpro\mysql\opgaveark1>
```

and the python file:

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect (
    host='localhost',
    user='oscar',
    pwd='password',
    database='gpro1'
)

cursor = db.cursor (dictionary = True)
cursor.execute ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (id INTEGER)")

for i in range (0,100):
    cursor.execute (f"INSERT INTO TestTable VALUE({i})")
db.commit ()
```

Comment: It might be the case that you don't installed it in the right location.
Which os and IDE are you using?

Comment: im on windows. What is an IDE excactly?

Comment: How did you install the package? Did you use pip? Did you use pip3? 
Did you use 'pip list' or 'pip3 list' to see if the package is installed? What is your Python version?

Comment: i used both pip and pip3 because it didnt work with only pip